# CSS not found for web app using Apache Tomcat 7.0

Tags: html, css, apache, tomcat, tomcat7

I have a web app that I have been developing from within Eclipse IDE and have been testing using a Tomcat sever, within Eclipse.  Throughout development I've had no issues with CSS files being inaccessible.

Now I'm at a point where I'm using a standalone instance of Apache Tomcat and my CSS files are simply not found?  When I try to access them via their URL a 404 error is produced.  The location of a CSS file within my project appears to make no difference;  I have tried it in a css/ folder and in the root folder of unfiltered pages.

I don't believe this to be an issue with the link I'm referring to the files with.

**CSS & Page Location**

```
-- OpportunityTracking (unpacked .war)
   -- webapps
      -- login.xhtml
      -- bootstrap.css
```

**CSS Reference in login.xhtml**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/OpportunityTracking/bootstrap.css" />
```

**web.xml**

```
<display-name>OpportunityTracking</display-name>
...
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>css</extension>
    <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This project was set up as a Maven project however, the javax.faces jar was added as a dependency outside of Maven.  Originally, javax.faces-2.1.26.jar was included as a referenced library in the eclipse project.

When faced with an unrelated issue, I removed this reference and included javax.faces-2.2.13.jar as a Maven dependency.  In doing this, I appeared to resolve my original issue of CSS and Images not being found.

Update: I suffered this issue again and explored the issue further. By creating a 'Resources' folder in the 'webapps' folder, and referencing the css files from here, I found that all access issues were resolved